# Libreoffice download unexpectedly large with non-matching hashes

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, download, libreoffice, hashing

Today I downloaded LibreOffice MSI for windows x86_64 and the download was taking quite long (about 1 or 2 minutes.) [The website](http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/5.3.2/win/x86_64/LibreOffice_5.3.2_Win_x64_helppack_en-US.msi.mirrorlist) said that it was **5.1MB** but chrome reported **223MB**. Windows explorer reports **232MB**. The SHA-256 of the MSI according to the website above is `bcc52a752acc9f073b442ed5c78f0939f94c2b3fb2a51efe786dbeb30237cb29`. However, because 7-ZIP adds a SHA-256 calculator in the context menu in windows explorer, I decided to hash it myself. The resulting hash was `bc361f37185cfa3c3090e7c500f043001585f74aof88e4bd158e804a5c2ed706`. **A different hash.**

Also, the SHA-1 from the site was `f5a1ef34f631a4df10619d9cc24d3b348b5ad4ee`, but the one calculated from the download was `a5d31a079733e78ed05be31e573b3bc34a662905`.

Is this LibreOffice not updating its hashes or a network problem? Should I be concerned?

Comment: The website says it is for the help pack, not for LibreOffice itself.  Which link did you use?  I downloaded from the [first link on the page](http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/5.3.2/win/x86_64/LibreOffice_5.3.2_Win_x64_helppack_en-US.msi) and it was indeed 5.1 MB, and the hashes matched.

Comment: I usually download libreoffice using the torrents ...